# returning each DOM elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I used 3 ways in my experiment in returning each HTML elements in an array:

- `elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {})`
- `[].forEach(elementsArray, function(elem) {})`
- `Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsArray, function(elem) {})`

In my HTML, I have the following elements:

```
<section id="example">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

First example:

```
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('#example').children.forEach(function(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
})
```

> Uncaught TypeError: query(...).children.forEach is not a function

Second example:

```
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

[].forEach(query('#example').children, function(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
})
```

> Uncaught TypeError: `#<HTMLCollection>` is not a function

Third example:

```
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(query('#example').children, function(elem) {
  console.log(elem)
})
```

> `<div></div>`
> `<div></div>`
> `<div></div>`

My question is, what is it that makes these three different from each other in terms of returning DOM elements? And when should I use each?

Comment: You can use `querySelectorAll('#example > *')` to query all the direct children  of `#example`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First example:**

The `children` property of an element is an `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `forEach` method. So this option does not work.

**Second example:**

```
[].forEach(query('#example').children, function(elem) {
```

This attempts to use the children `HTMLCollection` as a callback function. It's not a function, so this does not work.

You could do:

```
[].forEach.call(query('#example').children, function(elem) {
```

**Third example:**

`Array.prototype.forEach.call` is roughly equivalent to the `[].forEach.call` method, except it does not create a new array object. This one will work.

**Another Option:**

Another slightly-different option would be to use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which does have a `forEach` method.

```
var queryAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

queryAll('#example > *').forEach(function(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
})
```

However, the `forEach` method of `NodeList` is a newer addition, and browser support is still lacking. You could polyfill it though.

Comment: So does it mean there are methods and properties that are only compatible for HTMLCollection and NodeList?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

```
<section>
  <div class="foo">Foo</div>
  <div class="foo">Foo</div>
  <div class="foo">Foo</div>
</section>
```

---

```
var section = document.querySelector('section');
section.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/umwthm68/)

Comment: The OP is using the *children* collection.

Comment: @RobG See my revised answer.